# I am trying to create a new category on a discord server using discord js but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, discord

```js
Client.on("message", (message) => {
  let careServer = Client.guilds.cache.find(c => c.id == "861168621350027306");
  console.log(careServer) //logs "861168621350027306"

  careServer.createChannel("Category 1", "category")
});

Client.login(token)
```

> "(node:4956) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: careServer.createChannel is not a function"

Comment: Should it be `const careServer = Client.guilds.cache.get("861168621350027306");`?

Comment: @Nick still doesnt work, but thanks anyway!